# Getting null results from the accuracy function in fabletools package

Tags: r, time-series, fable-r, fable

I have a time series that looks like this
t value
1 12
2 12
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
I expect acf1 to equal 0.443, but instead the accuracy function produces null. The code is as following:

```
df = data.frame("t" = 1:7, "value" = c(12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
tsb = df %>%
as_tsibble(index = t)
md = tsb %>% model(arima = ARIMA(value ~ PDQ(period = 4), stepwise = F))

fc = md %>% forecast(h = 4)

accuracy(fc, tsb)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example next time. Some help for creating good examples can be found here: https://www.tidyverse.org/help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ACF1` column from `accuracy()` is the first auto-correlation of the residuals. The ACF1 of 0.443 that you expect is the first auto-correlation of your data, which can be obtained with:

```r
library(feasts)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
df = data.frame("t" = 1:7, "value" = c(12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
tsb = df %>%
  as_tsibble(index = t)
tsb %>% ACF(lag_max = 1)
#> Response variable not specified, automatically selected `var = value`
#> # A tsibble: 1 x 2 [1]
#>     lag   acf
#>   <lag> <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.443
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The second problem with your usage is that `accuracy()` for forecasts requires future data to compute the forecast errors. The forecasts in `fc` do not match the times provided by `tsb`, and so no forecast errors can be computed.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(fable)

md = tsb %>% model(arima = ARIMA(value ~ PDQ(period = 4), stepwise = F))
fc = md %>% forecast(h = 4)

# Make up some future data for evaluating forecast accuracy
tsb_future <- new_data(tsb, 4) %>% mutate(value = rnorm(4))
# Compute the accuracy of the forecasts against the tsb_future scenario
accuracy(fc, tsb_future)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 9
#>   .model .type     ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE    ACF1
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 arima  Test  -0.779  1.09 0.975   100   100   NaN -0.0478
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!