# Null result for ACF1 from accuracy function

Tags: r, forecasting, fable

I fit a naive model to a time series and got null for the ACF1 column. I thought it should always have a numerical result since it's just a correlation? Why is this null?
Following is my code:

```
library('fable')
library('feasts')
library('dplyr')

df = data.frame("t" = 1:7, "value" = c(12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
tsb = df %>%
  as_tsibble(index = t)
train = tsb %>% filter(t < 6)

md = train %>% model(naive = NAIVE(value))
fc = md %>% forecast(h = 4)
accuracy(fc, tsb)
```

Thanks!

P.s.: This is a follow-up question for this question:
[Getting null results from the accuracy function in fabletools package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387422/getting-null-results-from-the-accuracy-function-in-fabletools-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four forecasts, but only 2 values in the test set, so `accuracy` can only work with the first 2 forecasts. That gives it 2 forecast errors, and it is not possible to compute an autocorrelation from 2 values.

Here is an example with four values in the test set:

```r
library(fable)
library(dplyr)

tsb <- data.frame(
    t = 1:9,
    value = c(12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = t)

md <- tsb %>%
  filter(t < 6) %>%
  model(naive = NAIVE(value))
md %>%
  forecast(h = 4) %>%
  accuracy(data = tsb)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 9
#>   .model .type    ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE  ACF1
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 naive  Test    0.5 0.707   0.5   100   100 0.167  0.25
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This particular addition of points works, though I still wonder why it doesn't when I add two 0s at the end? That is, if I have value = c(12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), I still get null for ACF1.

Comment: Because all the forecasts are zero, and all the actuals are zero, so all the errors are zero. You are asking for the autocorrelations of a series of zeros which is undefined.